# Is there any way to join the same two tables many times easily?

Tags: join, sqlite

I have two tables named "Player" and "Match". In "Player", There are two columns: Player.id and Player.name and in the "Match" table I have many columns related to about 20000 soccer matches, 22 of them relating to the players that have played in a particular match.

In the "Match" table, I have player ids in their respective columns, lets say I want a Query that shows the names of the Players in each match.(I want to replace their ids with their names). to do so, I have to join these two tables 22 times, one for each player.
For example to get player1's name:

```
select Match.id, Match.date, p1.name
from Match, Player as p1
Where Match.home_player1 == p1.id
```

Now if I want to get for example player2's name too, I have to do another join. which will be:

```
select Match.id, Match.date, p1.name, p2.name
from Match, Player as p1, Player as p2
Where Match.home_player1 == p1.id and Match.home_player2 == p2.id
```

And if I want to get all the 22 players, i have to do 22 joins. This is both inconvenient and in my opinion very inefficient as the number of rows is large.

Is there any convenient way to do what i want?

If it helps, the database is in sqlite and it does not matter if all the names end up in one column with a separator between them.

Comment: Do you make a table with `home_player1`, `home_player2`, ... `home_player22` columns? If so then search for UNPIVOT feature in your DBMS... or join 22 table copies. And the best way - normalize the structure.

Comment: If you could include which DBMS system you are using, then @Akina or somebody else could provide you with an `UNPIVOT` solution. I'm not very good at that, hence my suggestion for a DB redesign.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is from a downloaded data set and is not my design.@Akina I will search for that. thank you. @john-k-n i have included my dbms and its sqlite. i'll check your answer. thanks

Comment: Does the `Match` table contain columns named `away_player1` ... `away_player11` ? Guessing, because of the `home_player1` ... etc.

Comment: Yes. There is 11 columns for each team's players in this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better (design) solution would be to have another table named `matchplayer`. This simplistic table would consist of the two columns `match_id` and `player_id`.

You then `JOIN` on the `match_id` and then on the `player_id`.

```
SELECT m.id, m.date, p.name from 
FROM Match as m 
    JOIN matchplayer as mp
        ON mp.match_id = m.id
    JOIN Player as p
        ON mp.player_id = p.id
```

It doesn't matter if you have only 11, 10 or 12 players for that match. You always get a full list of players that participated in a given match. This could even include substitutions.

## Small Example to Unpivot into New Table

I've created a small example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e81582926398121c2704300b3d7ce388) to show you how you could unpivot the data from the match table into a new table to retrieve the player's name with slightly more ease.

#### Player Table

```
create table Player (
id int,
name varchar(100)
)
```

...and some data:

```
insert into Player
(
    id, name
)
values 
(1, 'Bernd Leno (1)'), 
(2, 'Aaron Ramsdate (32)'), 
(3, 'Kieran Tierney (3)'), 
(4, 'Nick Pope (1)'), 
(5, 'Will Norris (25)'), 
(6, 'Wayne Hennessey (13)')
```

#### Match Table

```
create table Match
(
    id int, 
    matchdate date, 
    home_player1 int, 
    home_player2 int, 
    home_player3 int, 
    away_player1 int, 
    away_player2 int, 
    away_player3 int
)
```

...and some data to go with it:

```
insert into Match (id, matchdate, home_player1, home_player2, home_player3, away_player1, away_player2, away_player3)
values
(1, '2021-09-29', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
(2, '2021-09-30', 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3)
```

#### MatchPlayer Table

This is the table we are going to use to join afterwards

```
create table MatchPlayer 
(
    match_id int, 
    player_id int
)
```

#### Selected Unpivoted Data

```
select match_id, player_id from 
(select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player1 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player2 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player3 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player1 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player2 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player3 as player_id from Match

) as unpivottable
```

Results in:

> ```
> match_id | player_id
> -------: | --------:
>        1 |         1
>        2 |         4
>        1 |         2
>        2 |         5
>        1 |         3
>        2 |         6
>        1 |         4
>        2 |         1
>        1 |         5
>        2 |         2
>        1 |         6
>        2 |         3
> ```

#### Insert Selected Unpivoted Data into MatchPlayer

```
insert into matchplayer
select match_id, player_id from 
(select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player1 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player2 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.home_player3 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player1 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player2 as player_id from Match
UNION ALL
select Match.id as match_id, Match.away_player3 as player_id from Match

) as unpivottable
where unpivottable.match_id
```

#### Retrieve Simple Match Overview

```
SELECT m.id, m.matchdate, p.name  
FROM Match as m 
    JOIN MatchPlayer as mp
        ON mp.match_id = m.id
    JOIN Player as p
        ON mp.player_id = p.id
```

Results in:

> ```
> id | matchdate  | name                
> -: | :--------- | :-------------------
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Bernd Leno (1)      
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Aaron Ramsdate (32) 
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Kieran Tierney (3)  
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Nick Pope (1)       
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Will Norris (25)    
>  1 | 2021-09-29 | Wayne Hennessey (13)
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Bernd Leno (1)      
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Aaron Ramsdate (32) 
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Kieran Tierney (3)  
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Nick Pope (1)       
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Will Norris (25)    
>  2 | 2021-09-30 | Wayne Hennessey (13)
> ```

This is a very quick example bases on some assumptions.

#### On a Side Note

The data of the players was taken from Premier League's homepage as of today (2021-10-04) from the teams **Burnley FC** and  **Arsenal**.

Comment: As i mentioned, this is a downloaded dump, so design is what it is. any suggestions to convert my data's design to what you described?

Comment: Sadly sqlite does not support `UNPIVOT` so you'll have to do with this: [Turn SQLite columns to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780565/turn-sqlite-columns-to-rows).

Comment: Yes, it seems i have to do either the join or creating the Intermediary table(that you described) by hand.

Comment: I've added an example on how you could achieve the desired `MatchPlayer`  table. You could split it into `home`  and `away` columns. You could then have a `MatchPlayer` table with three columns `match_id`, `player_id`, `home_flag`. Hope this gets you flying.